# Xcode Auto Layout Constraints Not Working Properly in Static Table View Cell

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout

For some reason, auto layout constraints are not working correctly in my static table view. Below are what the constraints for the switches look like in storyboard.

[image: Constraints for switch in first cell]

[image: Constraints for switch in second cell]

As can be seen, the constraints are identical for both switches to their respective surrounding elements and views. Below are what the constraints for the labels look like in storyboard.

[image: Constraints for label in first cell]

[image: Constraints for label in second cell]

As can be seen again, the constraints are identical for both labels to their respective surrounding elements and views. However, as can be seen below, the elements in the second table view cell in the functionality section are displayed incorrectly on the device screen. Not only are the elements displayed incorrectly, but they are displayed in a different manner than the first cell, whose elements had identical constraints. Why is this occurring and how can this be fixed? Could it possibly be as simple as an Xcode glitch?

[image: iPhone simulator screen]

Comment: Set constant width for Switch, and for label check autoshrink.

Comment: @BohdanSavych Setting a constant width for the switch seems to be the fix to the problem. Thanks! By the way, where is the autoshrink option for labels in storyboard? Or is it done programmatically?

Comment: yes, i already edit my answer,I'm glad it helped.

Comment: Set it on storyboard and your text will shrink according to size of UILabel  http://cs631229.vk.me/v631229174/45366/5N7ATgBnMeE.jpg

Comment: @BohdanSavych Ah okay, thanks for the help.